# find specific value that meets conditions - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Trying to create new column with values that meet specific conditions. Below I have set out code which goes some way in explaining the logic but does not produce the correct output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-08-06 09:00:00', '2019-08-06 12:00:00', '2019-08-06 18:00:00', '2019-08-06 21:00:00', '2019-08-07 09:00:00', '2019-08-07 16:00:00', '2019-08-08 17:00:00' ,'2019-08-09 16:00:00'], 
                'type': [0, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 0 ,0], 
                'colour': ['blue', 'red', np.nan, 'blue', np.nan, np.nan, 'blue', 'red'],
                'maxPixel': [255, 7346, 32, 5184, 600, 322, 72, 6000],
                'minPixel': [86, 96, 14, 3540, 528, 300, 12, 4009],
                'colourDate': ['2019-08-06 12:00:00', '2019-08-08 16:00:00', '2019-08-06 23:00:00', '2019-08-06 22:00:00', '2019-08-08 09:00:00', '2019-08-09 16:00:00', '2019-08-08 23:00:00' ,'2019-08-11 16:00:00'] })

max_conditions = [(df['type'] == 1) & (df['colour'] == 'blue'),
                  (df['type'] == 1) & (df['colour'] == 'red')]


max_choices = [np.where(df['date'] <= df['colourDate'], max(df['maxPixel']), np.nan),
                np.where(df['date'] <= df['colourDate'], min(df['minPixel']), np.nan)]


df['pixelLimit'] = np.select(max_conditions, max_choices, default=np.nan)
```

**Incorrect output:**

```
                  date  type colour  maxPixel  minPixel           colourDate  pixelLimit
0  2019-08-06 09:00:00   0.0   blue       255        86  2019-08-06 12:00:00         NaN
1  2019-08-06 12:00:00   1.0    red      7346        96  2019-08-08 16:00:00        12.0
2  2019-08-06 18:00:00   NaN    NaN        32        14  2019-08-06 23:00:00         NaN
3  2019-08-06 21:00:00   1.0   blue      5184      3540  2019-08-06 22:00:00      6000.0
4  2019-08-07 09:00:00   NaN    NaN       600       528  2019-08-08 09:00:00         NaN
5  2019-08-07 16:00:00   NaN    NaN       322       300  2019-08-09 16:00:00         NaN
6  2019-08-08 17:00:00   0.0   blue        72        12  2019-08-08 23:00:00         NaN
7  2019-08-09 16:00:00   0.0    red      6000      4009  2019-08-11 16:00:00         NaN
```

**Explanation why output is incorrect:**

Value `12.0` in index row 1 for column `df['pixelLimit']` *is incorrect* because this value is from `df['minPixel']` index row 6 which has has a `df['date']` datetime of `2019-08-08 17:00:00` which is greater than the `2019-08-08 16:00:00` `df['date']` datetime contained in index row 1.

Value `6000.0` in index row 3 for column `df['pixelLimit']` *is incorrect* because this value is from `df['maxPixel']` index row 7 which has a `df['date']` datetime of `2019-08-09 16:00:00` which is greater than the `2019-08-06 22:00:00` `df['date']` datetime contained in index row .

**Correct output:**

```
                  date  type colour  maxPixel  minPixel           colourDate  pixelLimit
0  2019-08-06 09:00:00   0.0   blue       255        86  2019-08-06 12:00:00         NaN
1  2019-08-06 12:00:00   1.0    red      7346        96  2019-08-08 16:00:00        14.0
2  2019-08-06 18:00:00   NaN    NaN        32        14  2019-08-06 23:00:00         NaN
3  2019-08-06 21:00:00   1.0   blue      5184      3540  2019-08-06 22:00:00      5184.0
4  2019-08-07 09:00:00   NaN    NaN       600       528  2019-08-08 09:00:00         NaN
5  2019-08-07 16:00:00   NaN    NaN       322       300  2019-08-09 16:00:00         NaN
6  2019-08-08 17:00:00   0.0   blue        72        12  2019-08-08 23:00:00         NaN
7  2019-08-09 16:00:00   0.0    red      6000      4009  2019-08-11 16:00:00         NaN
```

**Explanation why output is correct:**

Value `14.0` in index row 1 for column `df['pixelLimit']` *is correct* because we are looking for the minimum value in column `df['minPixel']` which has a datetime in column `df['date']` less than the datetime in index row 1 for column `df['colourDate']` and greater or equal to the datetime in index row 1 for column `df['date']`

Value `5184.0` in index row 3 for column `df['pixelLimit']` *is correct* because we are looking for the maximum value in column `df['maxPixel']` which has a datetime in column `df['date']` less than the datetime in index row 3 for column `df['colourDate']` and greater or equal to the datetime in index row 3 for column `df['date']`

**Considerations:**

Maybe `np.select` is not best suited for this task and some sort of function might serve the task better?

Also, maybe I need to create some sort of dynamic `len` to use as a starting point for each row?

**Request**

Please can anyone out there help me amend my code to achieve the correct output

Comment: Sorry about that typo @sammywemmy and Allolz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For matching problems like this one possibility is to do the complete merge, then subset, using a Boolean Series, to all rows that satisfy your condition (for that row) and find the `max` or `min` among all the possible matches. Since this requires slightly different columns and different functions I split the operations into 2 very similar pieces of code, one to deal with 1/blue and the other for 1/red.

First some housekeeping, make things datetime

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['colourDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colourDate'])
```

---

Calculate the min pixel for 1/red between the times for each row

```
# Subset of rows we need to do this for
dfmin = df[df.type.eq(1) & df.colour.eq('red')].reset_index()

# To each row merge all rows from the original DataFrame
dfmin = dfmin.merge(df[['date', 'minPixel']], how='cross')
# If pd.version < 1.2 instead use: 
#dfmin = dfmin.assign(t=1).merge(df[['date', 'minPixel']].assign(t=1), on='t')

# Only keep rows between the dates, then among those find the min minPixel
smin = (dfmin[dfmin.date_y.between(dfmin.date_x, dfmin.colourDate)]
            .groupby('index')['minPixel_y'].min()
            .rename('pixel_limit'))
#index
#1    14
#Name: pixel_limit, dtype: int64
```

---

```
# Max is basically a mirror
dfmax = df[df.type.eq(1) & df.colour.eq('blue')].reset_index()

dfmax = dfmax.merge(df[['date', 'maxPixel']], how='cross')
#dfmax = dfmax.assign(t=1).merge(df[['date', 'maxPixel']].assign(t=1), on='t')

smax = (dfmax[dfmax.date_y.between(dfmax.date_x, dfmax.colourDate)]
           .groupby('index')['maxPixel_y'].max()
           .rename('pixel_limit'))
```

---

Finally because the above groups over the original index (i.e. `'index'`) we can simply assign back to align with the original DataFrame.

```
df['pixel_limit'] = pd.concat([smin, smax])

                 date  type colour  maxPixel  minPixel          colourDate  pixel_limit
0 2019-08-06 09:00:00   0.0   blue       255        86 2019-08-06 12:00:00          NaN
1 2019-08-06 12:00:00   1.0    red      7346        96 2019-08-08 16:00:00         14.0
2 2019-08-06 18:00:00   NaN    NaN        32        14 2019-08-06 23:00:00          NaN
3 2019-08-06 21:00:00   1.0   blue      5184      3540 2019-08-06 22:00:00       5184.0
4 2019-08-07 09:00:00   NaN    NaN       600       528 2019-08-08 09:00:00          NaN
5 2019-08-07 16:00:00   NaN    NaN       322       300 2019-08-09 16:00:00          NaN
6 2019-08-08 17:00:00   0.0   blue        72        12 2019-08-08 23:00:00          NaN
7 2019-08-09 16:00:00   0.0    red      6000      4009 2019-08-11 16:00:00          NaN
```

---

If you need to bring along a lot of different information for the row with the min/max Pixel then instead of `groupby` `min/max` we will sort_values and then `gropuby` + `head` or `tail` to get the min or max pixel. For the min this would look like (slight renaming of suffixes):

```
# Subset of rows we need to do this for
dfmin = df[df.type.eq(1) & df.colour.eq('red')].reset_index()

# To each row merge all rows from the original DataFrame
dfmin = dfmin.merge(df[['date', 'minPixel']].reset_index(), how='cross', 
                    suffixes=['', '_match'])
# For older pandas < 1.2
#dfmin = (dfmin.assign(t=1)
#              .merge(df[['date', 'minPixel']].reset_index().assign(t=1), 
#                     on='t', suffixes=['', '_match'])) 

# Only keep rows between the dates, then among those find the min minPixel row. 
# A bunch of renaming. 
smin = (dfmin[dfmin.date_match.between(dfmin.date, dfmin.colourDate)]
            .sort_values('minPixel_match', ascending=True)
            .groupby('index').head(1)
            .set_index('index')
            .filter(like='_match')
            .rename(columns={'minPixel_match': 'pixel_limit'}))
```

The Max would then be similar using `.tail`

```
dfmax = df[df.type.eq(1) & df.colour.eq('blue')].reset_index()
dfmax = dfmax.merge(df[['date', 'maxPixel']].reset_index(), how='cross', 
                    suffixes=['', '_match'])

smax = (dfmax[dfmax.date_match.between(dfmax.date, dfmin.colourDate)]
            .sort_values('maxPixel_match', ascending=True)
            .groupby('index').tail(1)
            .set_index('index')
            .filter(like='_match')
            .rename(columns={'maxPixel_match': 'pixel_limit'}))
```

And finally we concat along `axis=1` now that we need to join multiple columns to the original:

```
result = pd.concat([df, pd.concat([smin, smax])], axis=1)
```

---

```
                  date  type colour  maxPixel  minPixel           colourDate  index_match           date_match  pixel_limit
0  2019-08-06 09:00:00   0.0   blue       255        86  2019-08-06 12:00:00          NaN                  NaN          NaN
1  2019-08-06 12:00:00   1.0    red      7346        96  2019-08-08 16:00:00          2.0  2019-08-06 18:00:00         14.0
2  2019-08-06 18:00:00   NaN    NaN        32        14  2019-08-06 23:00:00          NaN                  NaN          NaN
3  2019-08-06 21:00:00   1.0   blue      5184      3540  2019-08-06 22:00:00          3.0  2019-08-06 21:00:00       5184.0
4  2019-08-07 09:00:00   NaN    NaN       600       528  2019-08-08 09:00:00          NaN                  NaN          NaN
5  2019-08-07 16:00:00   NaN    NaN       322       300  2019-08-09 16:00:00          NaN                  NaN          NaN
6  2019-08-08 17:00:00   0.0   blue        72        12  2019-08-08 23:00:00          NaN                  NaN          NaN
7  2019-08-09 16:00:00   0.0    red      6000      4009  2019-08-11 16:00:00          NaN                  NaN          NaN
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. More and more I'm getting to see the vast and wide applicability of `groupby`.

Comment: I think a cross join could help instead of the `assign` here: ``dfmin = dfmin.assign(t=1).merge(df[['date', 'minPixel']].assign(t=1), on='t')``

Comment: using the the cross join causes a problem with this part...`smin = (dfmin[dfmin.date_y.between(dfmin.date_x, dfmin.colourDate)]
            .groupby('index_x')['minPixel_y'].min()
            .rename('pixel_limit'))`

Comment: ah.. yes, I was a bit hasty

Comment: Guys the code worked very efficiently on a df with over 100k rows! However, it is very difficult for me to manually check what row index the `pixel_limit` has been pulled from. How can I add another column to reference the row index or `date` where the `pixel_limit` value has been pulled @sammywemmy and ALollz